# In Eclipse (Spring Source) Grails always build in production mode

Tags: eclipse, grails, environment, production

When using Eclipse for your Grails projects the building of the war seems to be stuck in production mode.

If you want to deploy to an attached tcServer you simply right click on your project then choose “run as” ->“run on server”.

If you have your grails project set to “dev” (right click on your project then choose “properties”->”grails”->”run on server”) then you would expect the project to build a development war.
You’d be wrong. You get a production build.

How do you get a eclipse to build a development war?

Comment: I am facing the same prob. My grails project will always set to production environment even if I set it to run-app. and it copies file to my directory..it says this:Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1467ms.
Running script C:\grails-1.3.5\scripts\War.groovy
Environment set to production then nothing...nothing..I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Each Grails command has a default environment, e.g.

- grails run-app => dev
- grails test-app => test
- grails war => production

You can override this default by supplying an argument `-Dgrails.env=<environment>`. So to build a war for the dev environment, run `grails -Dgrails.env=dev war`

Comment: In STS you can also go into Right click on project > Properties > Grails > Rn On Server. In there you can specify which environment to run as.

Comment: Jarred - you should make this an answer not a comment

Answer (score 1):

Don, What you say is correct for the command line. I'm referring to Eclipse.

I have solved the problem.

It seems there is a bug in Eclipse. If you want your app built (through Eclipse) as development then set the “dev” to “test”.

As it stands with you cannot get Eclipse to build a dev war.
The version of eclipse I am using is Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149.