# eclipse/sts environment always set to production

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, environment

I am having trouble running my grails app. Everytime I save something, it builds and run. And everytime I run/it runs, it shows that it is set to development then continues until it shows "Environment set to production " then creates war file.

My previous solution was to stop the grails app, go to task manager and 'kill' the javaw.exe that it creates. But this time it creates two javaw.exe (it used to create java.exe and javaw.exe). I also tried the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910418/in-eclipse-spring-source-grails-always-build-in-production-mode) but did not solve it.

it shows these lines in my console:

```
Dependencies resolved in 8324ms.
Running script E:\grails-1.3.5\grails-1.3.5\scripts\War.groovy
Environment set to test
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to E:\workspace\grails\target\classes
     [gspc] Compiling 382 GSP files for package [grails] to E:\workspace\grails\target\classes
     [gspc] Compiling 2 GSP files for package [auditLogging] to E:\workspace\grails\target\classes
     [gspc] Compiling 1 GSP file for package [searchable] to E:\workspace\grails\target\classes
Building WAR file ...
     [copy] Copying 168 files to C:\Users\someuser\.grails\1.3.5\projects\grails\stage
```

Any idea how to solve this? thanks

Comment: two javaw.exe? one must be javaw runnning STS

Comment: actually I am using sts.

Answer (score 0):

Grails is a really smart framework with gradle as its build tool and whenever it creates a war it thinks you have made it for production purposes as it generally mean.
If you want to create a war with development environment then you can do:

```
grails dev war
```

It will create war file with environment set to development and also grails provide many other cool thing for building war:

```
grails test war
grails dev war
grails prod war
```

So if you using STS then do not use `grails dev war` just `dev war`
I think about commands explains itself and If you want to know more about `grails war` command better look in most awesome documentation i have ever seen [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/war.html).
This link refers to documentation of grails latest version if you are using some older version, help yourself.